# Difference between StandardController and StandardSetController?

Tags: standardcontroller, standardsetcontroller

I have read documents for `StandardSetController`, but I don't understand what it is or why to use it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ApexPages.StandardController` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm)) encapsulates just a single Sobject (e.g. Account, Opportunity).

`ApexPages.StandardSetController` ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm)) contains a list of records (one or more), and has additional functions to facilitate pagination (moving between pages) and updating a number of records at once.

For example in test class when we initialize

**ApexPages.StandardController**

```
Account objAccount = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 1];
ApexPages.StandardController standctrl = new ApexPages.StandardController(objAccount );
```

**ApexPages.StandardSetController**

```
List<account> accountList = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 20];
ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(accountList);
```

Comment: suppose in ApexPages.StandardController i will change limit 1 to 20 then whats type of effects change.
Account objAccount = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 20];
ApexPages.StandardController standctrl = new ApexPages.StandardController(objAccount );

Comment: @VipinIndora first your query will return list so you need to assign to `List<Account> lstAccount` and in `new ApexPages.StandardController(lstAccount[0]);` .. You need pass single record.. Beacuse if you check the documentation `StandardController` accept only one record..

Answer (score 1):

It is also important to note that

> The maximum record limit for StandardSetController is 10,000 records.
>   Instantiating StandardSetController using a query locator returning
>   more than 10,000 records causes a LimitException to be thrown.
>   However, instantiating StandardSetController with a list of more than
>   10,000 records doesn’t throw an exception, and instead truncates the
>   records to the limit.

so use the query locator instantiation to ensure you don't have unexpected truncation occurring.